# Determing winning on the server side or client side?

Tags: javascript, networking, node.js, websocket, card-game

I am using JavaScript + Node.js+Websockets to develop a multiplayer card game. In my single game version the Win determining calculation is done on the client side (of course) with a function.

It looks something like this:

```
function(CheckWin){
if (something) {
player1 win
document.getElementById("winning").innerHTML="reason"
}
else if (something) {
player2 win
document.getElementById("winning").innerHTML="reason"
}
else if (something) {
player1 win
document.getElementById("winning").innerHTML="reason"
}

}
```

It is a bit chunky but that is how it is. So in my multiplayer game I can either:

1. When all card values are collected, the server emits all the cards value
   to the client side and then it will execute the function there like
   it was in my single game (but I heard this is not SAFE)
2. Execute the function in the server side and then emit the result
   to the client (but I don't know how to emit all this
   information, comments, winning to client with socket.io, I think
   socket.io can only emit limited number of value types, I am planning
   to emit just the Boolean value win or lose).

I am new with programming/gaming so hopefully this question is not too silly.

Comment: Do you really have pure text comments in your code?

Comment: Yeah in my single game version whenever a winning condition is determined, the reason (text) will be shown on the screen. Doing this because I want the player know why they win or lose(the rule of the game is a bit complex)

Comment: I'm speaking about the `player 1 win` and `player 2 win` between the if and setting the text.

Answer (score 7):

Hello visitors of Jindsay's Card Game Forum. Here is your friend xXx_GameH4x0rPhilipp_xXx with another cheat for you. Do you want to win every game? Here is a simple hack which works with every web browser:

1. Press F12
2. Click on "Debugger"
3. Select `check_win.js`
4. There is now a window with lots of programming code. Don't worry, you don't need to understand any of it. Just click on the line number 65. There should now be a little icon on it.
5. Play the game to the end.
6. When the game is over, it will seem as if the game is frozen, but it's not. The program is just paused. There should now be a little arrow next to line 65 in the code window.
7. You will notice a window with variables to the right. Look for the variable `player1Score` and change it to `999999999`
8. Press F8 to continue the game.

The game will now say that you won the game, even when you lost.

This might change a little when jindsay updates the game. When it stops working, just send me a PM and I update above instructions. When jindsay reads this, he might try to make this more complicated and the above instructions might get a bit longer. But unless he moves all the game mechanics to the server and turns the client-sided programming into nothing but a dumb input-output interface, there will always be a way to do this cheat.

Have fun!

Comment: The sarcasm is strong in this one :v

Comment: Ok now I know I should definitely not let the client to do the determining job...

Comment: Please avoid sarcastic answers. Or at least wrap it into quote and post a sane TL;DR answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Kromster it's not sarcasm. Sarcasm is something like "Yeah, it's a great idea to let the client cheat, what could happen?"

Comment: @Bálint whatever it is, it's a poor fit for answer.

Comment: @Kromster Well, I think it answeres the question perfectly because it provided a scenario where one of the options fail.

Comment: @Bálint  *"provided a scenario where one of the options fail"* != *"answeres the question perfectly"*

Comment: @Kromster "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful" - stackoverflow help center.

Comment: @Bálint did I say it's not helpful? No point in arguing. I made my comment for Philipp, I hope he takes it into account.

Answer (score 5):

Doing basically anything on client-side apat from the inputs is a bad idea. And believe me, if the programmers could collect inputs on the server side, so the client couldn't fake them, then they would happily do so.

Literally anyone can change the code to always register a winning condition. If they make it send it back to the server, than it's even worse.

The client shouldn't be a game, it should be a renderer to visualize the data sent by the server, every gameplay logic should be handled on server-side.

Every player is a cheater.